# separation contacts according to social networks

Tags: contacts, telegram

is there any way to separate social network contacts and save it to a file ? like save "IMO" contacts in a file and save telegram contacts in another file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom filter of contacts sorted by socialnetaccount, then export it to SD[image: filter contacts]